# Mapbox dynamic data

Tags: mapbox

I have used Mapbox with great success using static datasets.

However I have a new project that I am starting and it will need to consume large weather datasets, perhaps live.

Im not certain if Mapbox is the right route but I would like to explore if other people think it might be possible? I have looking into other options such as Geoserver.

I have seen lots of examples of loading JSON on the client side. I would like to explore if its possible to dynamically load large JSON files (~500mb) from a database into mapbox then serve the resulting map on the client side with this data added in? The upload could be done daily first thing instead of being completed on the client side every time the map is loaded.

So the question is can I load datasets in the backend of Mapbox daily to be consumed on the client side?

Comment: Basically for the client to see that data, it is downloaded to the client. gzip and vector tiles will be your friends.Also using scale dependency limits may help in download smaller extents of data.

Comment: If it's only needed to be updated daily I don't see why you can't schedule this as an upload to Mapbox daily, then you get optimised maps via vector tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox GL JS supports OGC WMS. however many people are generating dynamic on the fly vector tiles even with weather data. Mapbox just recently blogged about it with sample code. We've done vector tiles from geoserver or from POSTGIS and from tippecanoe on server

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem so often that I created [martin](https://github.com/urbica/martin) — fast and lightweight vector tiles server. It allows you to generate vector tiles from [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database and use in with Mapbox GL JS.

In your case, you can upload all of your data into a database and use martin to display this data as a vector tiles on the frontend. So there is no need to upload large GeoJSON files on the frontend directly. Also, you can add dynamic filtering using [function sources](https://github.com/urbica/martin#function-sources).